# Issue with Google+ upgrade via OAuth2 and multiple sign-in

Tags: google-plus, google-oauth

I am using OAuth 2.0 with `plus.login` scope.
In order to handle multiple sign-in, I'd like to use the `login_hint` parameter. The request looks like

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
  redirect_uri=https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground&
  response_type=code&
  client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com&
  scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login&
  login_hint=user@gmail.com
```

It works in most cases, but I encounter an issue in a very specific situation :
if the account designated by `login_hint` is

- currently signed-in, but
- not the primary account, and
- has not upgraded to Google+

the user is redirected as expected to the Google+ upgrade form but, after a brief instant, again redirected, to an `Error 400 Unauthorized request` page.

Is this an expected behavior?

---

*Note:*
The problem seems to be that the user is redirected to
`https://plus.google.com/up?continue=...`
instead of
`https://plus.google.com/u/$i/up?continue=...`

Comment: Have you fixed this issue?

Comment: I found a way to work around it and moved on. Do you have the same problem?

Comment: I think that, its occurring because X-Frame-Options is blocking it.