# new account in google+ sign in

Tags: python, api, google-plus, google-oauth

I was able to link account with my site with `Google+ Api`,

One thing I am having problem is :

1. When the user links his new account(By means of not yet signed in Google+ social network) in my created api app
2. The user is directed to create a Google+ profile screen.
3. When submit button is pressed, it was directed to a URL then it doesnt load anymore leaving the screen blank not knowing if the user's account was created in google+.

**Question**: Is there a way to add or determine in the code that if the user hasn't created an account in the google+?

The other problem is when that account is link it is logged in the browser but displaying an error saying `"Failed to upgrade the authorization code"`

When I debugged my code it is having an error in the flow authentication:

```
try:
    # Upgrade the authorization code into a credentials object
    oauth_flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(os.getcwd()+path+'client_secrets.json', scope='')
    oauth_flow.redirect_uri = 'postmessage'
    credentials = oauth_flow.step2_exchange(code)
except FlowExchangeError:
    return 'Failed to upgrade the authorization code.'
```

Here is the parameters passed in my view:

```
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" />
<meta name="google-signin-requestvisibleactions" content="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity" />
<meta name="google-signin-cookiepolicy" content="single_host_origin" />
```

Is the problem related to the parameters? What could be the problem?

The problem is btw related to this question. [Issue with Google+ upgrade via OAuth2 and multiple sign-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440135/issue-with-google-upgrade-via-oauth2-and-multiple-sign-in?lq=1)

`client_secrets.json`:

```
{ "web":
  { "client_id": "1314.....googleusercontent.com",
    "client_secret": "Se8....",
    "client_email": "1314...@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
    "redirect_uris": [ "postmessage"],
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
  }
}
```

Hoping for your help. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like something is going wrong there to be honest - maybe an origin mismatch in the developers console? Is the page anywhere online to see?

Comment: @IanBarber, its not, origin mismatch is not the problem, It doesn display on the pop-up. I dont know what seems to be the problem, others are encountering it also. Could it be that there is something wrong with my client_secrets.json? What other codes do you need to see?

Comment: Can you see if the `FlowExchangeError` has a `message`? Try something like `except FlowExchangeError as e: print e.message`.

Comment: @GrégoireClermont, the error it produces is `invalid client`

Comment: @Bazinga It might be something with your `client_secrets.json`. Can you double-check it? See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets for reference.

Comment: You also need to set your scope for the `flow_from_secrets` line

Comment: @sshashank124, add the scope 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login' in the flow_from_secrets?

Comment: @GrégoireClermont, I posted the client_secrets.json above, is the `redirect_uris` needed? Because I havent set any.

Comment: @Bazinga, Yes I believe so.

Comment: @GrégoireClermont, I traced the error why it is not continuing. It has this error `Load denied by X-Frame-Options`.